# Incomplete response with Get Packages API with an authenticated client on BinTray

Tags: rest, api, package, bintray

I'm trying to use BinTray's `Get Packages` API with an authenticated client to list **all** the packages in a specific repository, and according to the documentation

> Get a list of packages in the specified repository, optionally specify a starting position and/or a name prefix filter This resource can be consumed by both authenticated and anonymous clients. For anonymous clients it will return no more than 50 results

But I'm not seeing all the packages from the specified repository. What am I missing here?

My request looks like this and I get about 40 out of the 150+ packages:
`GET https://bintray.com/api/v1/repos/<subject>/<repo>/packages`

Answer (score 0):

Bintray API returns only 50 results, if you want to see more, you will have to use the [pagination](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-Pagination) parameter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, the documentation is very ambiguous. I have created a ticket for this with JFrog.